# How to add a icon into Gmail toolbar?

Tags: gmail, gmail.js

give me an idea to add button to Gmail toolbar and also provide me a sample code if possible. i should add a button named save to Gmail toolbar. Code to add a button to Gmail toolbar using gmail.js.
i tried doing with add to tool bar method in gmail.js but it doesn't help me. guide mw with correct procedure for adding the button to the toolbar